# Python Save to different workbook

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have done code which save df to different spreadsheets ( in the single workbook), BUT is any source or sample where df can be saved (to_excel) to different excel workbooks?

Currently I use

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = name)
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
df.to_excel(writer, workbook_name = name)
```

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. You are supposed to do researh bvefore asking and provide what you found/did not help you.

Comment: @PatrickArtner have change the question a bit, it is related to the fact that I have tried to search in internet for some solution, but as result - nothing (only VBA-VBS) , that's why my question is related to "is it even possible at all" ??

Comment: Related: **[Why “the best choice” or “possible options” questions are always downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214215/370758)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "No" - a different workbook means a different file.

Create a new `writer` object, which you define via `pandas.ExcelWriter`.

Point it to another Excel file and apply `df.to_excel(writer2, sheetname='X')` to that one, with a `sheetname` of your choice.

This is a useful tutorial: [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html)

Comment: Is it any other "clever" function who could support it? To save to different file?

Comment: No. You can't get as clever as `df.to_excel`.

Comment: I mean you could just not do the work, and that's probably the most clever thing you could do; and something my co-workers often try to pull. But don't be that guy ;-)